# How to do patternmatching against HashDict in elixir?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

How can I do pattern matching against HashDict in Elixir? I can not find any decent information anywhere. 
So example I have is and it is bound to variable a:

```
#HashDict<[{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}]>
```

And lets say I want to get 2

I tried something like this to test a concept, but no luck:

```
[{"a",1}, {"b",val} = a
```

But I get:  (MatchError) no match of right hand side value

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Okay, I asked the same question on [elxir-talk google group][1] and as it turns out, there is no way I can do pattern matching on HashDict, but as of Elixir 0.13 map data type will be available and it can be patternmatched against. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/UH_Iw8KC_ys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pattern match on a HashDict. In general, when you see something printed as `#HashDict<...>` it is exactly because its internal representation is "private". Maps are coming on Elixir 0.13 and they will support pattern matching (and other goodies).